# How to Capture only First Occurrence in Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy

I'm using Perl for the first time (with TextWrangler), and need help with regex!

I have a large string of species names, DNA, and other text. I want to extract the following:

```
Homo sapiens
Pongo abelii
Macaca mulatta
```

Right now, I've defined $string and have this command (sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology, I'm a total newbie):

```
while($string =~ m/(Homo sapiens|Pongo abelii|Macaca mulatta)/g)
{
    print "$1\n";
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Homo sapiens

Homo sapiens

Pongo abelii

Macaca mulatta

Homo sapiens

Homo sapiens

Homo sapiens

Homo sapiens

Homo sapiens

Homo sapiens
```

How do I get just *ONE* of each species name? This has been driving me crazy!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to remove duplicates, so use the standard code to do so.

```
my %seen;
while ($string =~ /(Homo sapiens|Pongo abelii|Macaca mulatta)/g) {
    print "$1\n" if !$seen{$1}++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's more to this than you are telling us, or you could just do:

```
print "Homo sapiens\nPongo abelii\nMacaca mulatta\n";
```

But to answer your question:

```
my %seen;
while($string =~ m/(Homo sapiens|Pongo abelii|Macaca mulatta)/g)
{
    print "$1\n" unless $seen{$1}++;
}
```

Or, more complicated, keep track of what you are looking for and stop when you've found them all:

```
my %not_found = ( 'Homo sapiens' => 1, 'Pongo abelii' => 1, 'Macaca mulatta' => 1 );
while ( %not_found && $string =~ /(@{[ join( '|', map quotemeta, sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %not_found) ]})/g ) {
    print "$1\n";
    delete $not_found{$1};
}
```

Comment: I know I could just print, but I need to use regex for an assignment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `g` modifier from the end of your regex.  That stands for "global" and will match all; without it, only the first is matched.